# Number of GWT RemoteServiceServlets

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

When designing an application with a large number of remote services, is it better to have one [RemoteServiceServlet](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuidePlumbingDiagram) end point with many methods or a large number of [RemoteServiceServlet](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuidePlumbingDiagram) endpoints with fewer methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with lots of RemoteServiceServlets, one per area of functionality or module in your application. Otherwise you end up with a "kitchen sink" of unrelated functionality all in one class.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that the question doesn't list the correct answer.

The command pattern offers you single end-point / single method solution for GWT-PRC.

Please see this [presentation](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/GoogleWebToolkitBestPractices.html) and you might find this [out of the box implementation](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-dispatch/) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest  that you integrate your server side with some sort of dispatcher servlet like Spring, so you can ease the development, and then go with David Tinker's suggestion. You should design your app according to your functionalities.